# Nuxt.js Управление маршрутизацией по api

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs

Я новичок во Vue и Nuxt.
Есть некоторый сайт, назовем его https://site.ru.
Исторически так сложилось что все ссылки на сайте вида https://site.ru/alias и поменять это нельзя.
alias - это некоторая строка (например "kakoi_to_alias")
Данные получаю по api, передавая этот самый alias в качестве параметра.
В ответ получаю данные соответствующие этому alias'у в т.ч. тип страницы:
response = {
type: 'catalog',
data: {...}
}
По alias'у нельзя понять к какому типу страницы он относится.
Каждому типу страницы соответствует свой шаблон. Их штук 10 разных.

Вопрос в следующем: Как в таких условиях можно можно организовать маршрутизацию.
Какие есть варианты?

Comment: А сделать Вы что хотите? По Вашему описанию понятно, что в приложении был роутинг, и вы хотите роутниг. К чему тут типы?..

Comment: Нет. Приложение только создается. Сейчас есть старый сайт с минимумом функционала, который как-то работает. Бизнесу этого уже не хватает. Принято решение о ребрендинге, расширении функционала и переводе фронта на современные технологии. Задача сохранить принцип маршрутизации старого сайта.

Comment: На основании значения поля type должно определяться какой шаблон страницы загружать

Comment: Но в Nuxt так не работает, здесь вы пишете свой роутинг (автоматически структурой файлов или зафодите свою логику через Vue Router), у Вас в любом случае endpoint не будет содержать такой же адрес, потому что это API. В Nuxt можно вручную указать внешний шаблон, в скрипте `layout: 'название',`, опять же можно свою логику роутера написать (это мало толку дает, как правило). Но задача от этого понятнее не становится, что Вы вообще пытаетесь сделать, нужно как-то конкретнее?

Comment: Тогда на примерах:
Ссылка site.ru/alias - ведет на страницу каталога (значение поля type="razdel")
Ссылка site.ru/drugoi_alias - ведет на страницу каталога в соседний раздел (значение поля type="razdel")
Ссылка site.ru/eshe_alias - ведет на страницу товара (значение поля type="product")

Comment: Ссылка site.ru/kakoi_to_alias - ведет на информационную страницу (значение поля type="content")
Ссылка site.ru/snova_alias - ведет на страницу уточняющего выбора (значение поля type="sublinks")
ну и т.д. всего вариантов страниц штук 10.
Каждому значению поля type соответствует своя страница (page, а не layout)
layout в целом один используется

Comment: Вся проблема сейчас в том как загружать нужный страничный шаблон полученный по api из поля type

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать пакет
[@nuxtjs/router](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module#readme)

Если я правильно понял задачу, то alias к странице можно получить как параметр и дальше как-то с ним работать. В том числе получить данные перед рендером самого компонента или страницы

Comment: Все наоборот. Алиас известен заранее и по нему я получаю данные для страницы. Проблема в том что заранее неизвестно какая страница соответствует алиасу

Comment: @ForumForum можно подробнее флоу,  чет не ясно
"Ссылка site.ru/kakoi_to_alias - ведет на информационную страницу (значение поля type="content") Ссылка site.ru/snova_alias - ведет на страницу уточняющего выбора (значение поля type="sublinks")"

у вас есть заранее известные алисы/роуты, но вы не знаете вот это поле type? а что это за поле? как вы его получаете, если заранее не знаете?

Comment: Описал же вроде бы в самом вопросе.
Алиас - передаю как параметр в запросе данных по api
Получаю данные из api: {type: "sublinks", data: {.......}}
поле type приходит по api